# Message box size should depend from message size in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make the div element changed its size depending on texts size from `<span id="dykSelectedReadMore">`.

```
<div class="flipper-back">

<a href="#" class="js-flipper-flip flipper-close"></a>
<div class="pad-box">
    <h3 class="colored">Did you know</h3>
    <div class="pad-30-0-0">
        <b><span id="dykSelectedIssue">som text</span></b>
        <br><br>
        <span id="dykSelectedReadMore">...e-identities by 2025.  Estonia introduced e-residency in 2014. Non-residents can get ID certificates with the functionality of Estonian ID card. This allows them to start using Estonian digital services from anywhere on Earth. E-residency is attracting entrepreneurs needing an investment account in the European Union, and is bringing more customers to Estonian companies and more capital into the country's economy.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which div do you want to resize ? Also, it's more likely to do with CSS than javascript.

Comment: go for some plugins ...

Comment: Try to apply float style for the parent div and check it

Comment: @RemyGrandin how to do it with css?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: @user3478286 share your css too.

Comment: `<div>` element by default resize according to its content.
Could you show us the real scenario? (I suggest to use [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) )

Comment: I have provided picture of my problem above. I it's not enough I will try to provide example

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't use Javascript, use CSS instead. This kind of problem occurs when div contains *floating* elements can't calculate its right height (because doesn't consider height of those elements).

Following the easiest and fastest way to solve.

Start adding this CSS code:

```
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */
```

(source [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/))

Than apply that class to the `flipper-back` div or `pad-box`.
Depends on witch `<div>` contains *floating* elements.

eg. `<div class="flipper-back clearfix">`